# Xcode 7 Creating correct App Icon Images

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

So Ive raised a topic on this before because its something that has created a lot of confusion for me, and I'm sure it has for a lot of other users. Currently I have my Xcode project and my assets manager as comes supplied with every project created. by default an AppIcon already exists in here which looks a little like so...

[image: 1st app icon image]

You can see that this (the default) AppIcon has 3 types of icon that have to be loaded in. Currently I have 3 images:

a 87x87@3x

a 120x120@3x

and a 180x180@3x.

I have no idea what the extension means (the @3x bit) so it would be nice if someone wouldn't mind explaining that to me aswell. But back to the main problem I'm having...

I find that when I go to create a new AppIcon, although its not necessary as I could just replace the images in the old AppIcon that is created by default, it does have a different interface which looks as follows:

[image: new app icon interface]

Now you should be able to see that the the "slots" in the new AppIcon are empty because I have absolutely no idea about what dimension images I am supposed to be supplying and to where they are supposed to go to within here. I also have no idea what extensions my images are supposed to be using and how many I am supposed to have. The whole process seems quite overwhelming and ridiculously complicated. I'm utterly confused as to why apple have made this so inefficient and just plain confusing :/

I have been looking at an icon generator which seems rather useful (as recommended in my last thread):
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/asset-catalog-creator-app/id809625456?mt=12

and I have also had a look at this although it doesn't seem particularly helpful:
[http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/asset-catalog-creator-app/id809625456?mt=12)

I have mainly been looking at this however it doesn't seem to offer much help if I'm honest:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2

***So to sum things up...***

1. What resolution images do I need for app icons?
2. Which AppIcon template am I using, the default or a newly created?
3. What extensions do my images need? ("@2x", "@3x" etc.)
4. What do the extensions mean/do?

**Thanks anyways!**

**-Ryan**

***UPDATE 1!***

I have kindly been provided a great link for a app icon generator which works online, it seems very quick and very reliable and anyone having the same issues, I would recommend you give this a try :)
[IconMaker](http://makeappicon.com)

Comment: If you want a quick and easy-to-use offline app, you can use this App Icon Asset Catalog Generator: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1052532083 (disclaimer: my app)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@3x if for the new resolution on iPhone 6 Plus and iPhone 6s Plus.

@2x is for the normal retina resolution.

Its related to the resolution of the image. an image 40x40 needs 3 files:

```
image.png 40x40
image@2x.png 80x80
image@3x.png 120x120
```

this applies for all the images used in the app, not only the icon.

Have you tried this one? [MakeAppIcon](http://makeappicon.com/)

Its excellent to generate the icons.

Comment: thanks! so does it have anything to do with the actual resolution of the image or no? like can I have a 57x57@2x and a 57x57@3x as an example?

Comment: 57x57@2x is 114x114 but in the device will appear to be 57x57. 57x57@3x is 171x171, 3 time more

Comment: ohhhh ok.. Thanks a lot bro that clears things up a little, have a good day and thanks for the help :)

Comment: I have now! thank you that is going to be really helpful :P One other thing, in my app I have an image lets say its 1024x1024 but I am using code to manipulate it so that its alway the same size as the screen, will apple still refuse my app when I go to publish it because I haven't used the correct extensions? I think that the images are currently @3x...

Comment: There is no problem resizing the image programatically. Apple is not going to refuse your app because of that. But do not use the 2x or 3x on the code, use only the image name

Comment: ok thats brilliant then :) so my only problem will be with the app icons? thanks to the link though I should have that sorted soon.

Comment: MakeAppIcon requires an email address

Answer (score 1):

Older question, but I use the following shell script to convert a PNG to the different icon sizes. Just make sure your input file is big enough. I use something like 2048x2048 so it can generate everything.

For the convert commandline tool, first install Homebrew: https://brew.sh/

Then install ImageMagick via:

```
$ brew install imagemagick
```

Adapt the `orig` and `new_prefix` variables if you wish, then run the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

orig="appicon.png"
new_prefix="appicon_"

iphone_settings="58 87"
iphone_spotlight="80 120"
iphone_app="120 180"

ipad_settings="29 58"
ipad_spotlight="40 80"
ipad_app="76 152"
ipad_pro_app="167"

iphone_ipad_notification="20 40 60"

app_store_icons="512 1024"
launch_icons="640x1136 640x960 320x480 1536x2008 768x1004"

for i in $iphone_settings $iphone_spotlight $iphone_app $ipad_settings $ipad_spotlight $ipad_app $ipad_pro_app $app_store_icons $iphone_ipad_notification; do
    echo "Resizing to $i x $i"
    convert -resize $i $orig ${new_prefix}${i}.png
done
```